# Fedora 12 - login panel: disable automatic login

Tags: automatic-logon, fedora-12

I have just replaced my FC11 by the FC12. To put skype up and running I used autoten and choose to not have the automatic login enable. After running it the skype was working nicely. However the next time I restarted the machine, on the login panel appeared ""automatic login"" option.

I went to `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` and added the command

```
    AutomaticLoginEnable=false
```

Restart the system and although automatic login isn't active anymore, the ""automatic login"" option still appears as if it were an option to be picked from the login panel. I googled around but didn't find how to get rid of it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps removing the entire portion of the `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` file under the label `[Daemon]` would do the trick, i.e. delete the following:

```
[daemon]
AutomaticLoginEnable=true
AutomaticLogin=<username>
TimedLoginEnable=true
TimedLogin=<username>
TimedLoginDelay=0
```